# Expo has competability issue, and can't recognize latest node installed

Tags: node.js, expo

expo start (error):

> ERROR: Node.js v12.5.0 is no longer supported.

node -v

> v16.3.0

Os: Windows 10

Not sure why expo thinks that i have 12.5 installed on my pc and how do i let it know that v16 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow article helped to solve the issue:

https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-node-js-with-nvm-for-windows-ffbe5c7a2b47